# How are functions defined in Scheme?

Tags: function, lambda, functional-programming, scheme

According to my assignment, some of the values ​​defined below in Scheme-notation are functions. I need to determine the value if it is not a function. Otherwise, I have to determine what the function calculates.:

```
First:  (define res  (+ 1 1))
Second: (define res2 ((lambda (i) (* wert1 i)) 2))
```

Now as far as I am concerned, the `+` is the functions name and the `values 1,1` are the parameters of the function. Same for the seconds case. Lambda is a way to write functions in Scheme, isn't it? So I thought this must be a function too.

My solutions says that **both are not functions but values!**
Did I get something wrong or do my solutions have a twist?

Comment: Can you post the exact wording of the assignment?

Comment: I would really like to, but since it is in german and my english is rather bad, I think it might cause misunderstanding. But I will try to edit it.

Comment: If you post it in German, I can translate it to English for you.

Comment: Task in german: "Die nachfolgend in Scheme-Notation definierten Werte sind teilweise Funktionen. Bestimmen Sie den Wert, falls es sich nicht um eine Funktion handelt. Bestimmen Sie andernfalls, was die Funktion berechnet."

Comment: I don't read German, but the English explanation in the question itself seems perfectly reasonable, and consistent with the answers given: I agree that both of those expressions define non-function values.

Comment: Since you've learned some Swift: the first would be `let res = 1 + 1`; the second `let res2 = { (i: Int) -> Int in wert1 * i } (2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `+` and `(lambda (i) ...)` are functions. However that wasn't the question. The question was whether the defined values (i.e. `res` and `res2`) are functions.

`res` is defined to be equal to `(+ 1 1)`, which calls the `+` function with the arguments 1 1 (just as you said). The result of doing that is `2`. So `res` is equal to `2`, which is a number, not a function.

The same is true for the definition of `res2`: `(lambda (i) (* wert1 i))` is a function. But you're not defining `res2` to be equal to `(lambda (i) (* wert1 i))`<sup>1</sup>, you're defining it to be equal to the result of applying that function to the argument `2`. So you're supposed to answer what the result of applying that function to that argument is.

---

<sup>1</sup> That would look like this:

```
(define res3 (lambda (i) (* wert1 i)))
```

And in that case, "res3 is a function" would be the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks alot not only for answering the question but also playing the translator! Perfectly explained, I will try to use it on the other defined values and if I still have questions, I will be back! For now, thank you vm sir!

Comment: And to be precise `+`,  and `res3` are variables that evaluates to functions while `res`, and `res2` are also variables evaluates to other values. Function names in Scheme are just variables.